# Overriding pending transition with animation object instead of resource id

Tags: android, android-activity, xamarin, transition

Is there any way to override the pending transition by passing it actual Animation object instead of an ID to an animation resource?

From

```
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
```

To

```
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(new MyFadeInAnimation(), new MyFadeOutAnimation());
```

If not, is there a way for me to manually register an animation resource (and attain an ID) programatically?

I really do not want to define the activity transition animations as XML for other reasons.

Answer (score 3):

So one way to do this is to use Fragments. Set `overridePendingTransition(0,0);` for the `Activity`. and then in the `Fragment`, override `onCreateAnimator()` or if using the old animations, use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and override `onCreateAnimation()`.